# _this.testFormEl.nativeElement.submit is not a function for Form Post

Tags: post, angular6

I have a hidden form  in a dialog which I want to submit automatically.
HTML Code :

```
<form #formVal method="POST" [action]="urlvalue">
      <p *ngFor="let item of redirectData.RedirectData.Form.Parameter;
       let pindex = index;">
    <input type="hidden" [name]="item.name" [value]="item.value">
  </p>
  </ form>
```

`

In my previous angular 1.5 code I was doing

```
$timeout(() => {
                   angular.element('#3DSForm').submit();
                        }, 100);
```

and it was working but here in Angular 6 I tried using ViewChild in ngAfteronInit but still no luck I am getting error for native element, I even used ngNoform in my HTML but didn't work out.

```
@ViewChild('formVal') form: ElementRef;
             setTimeout(() => {
               this.form.nativeElement.submit();
          }, 200);
```

Kindly suggest what am I missing

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some element called `submit`.

Example:

`<input type="hidden" name="submit">`

Rename it to something else, e.g `btnSubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call click event for submit button like this,

```
<form #formVal method="POST" [action]="urlvalue">
    <div *ngFor="let item of redirectData.RedirectData.Form.Parameter; let pindex = index;">
      <input type="hidden" [name]="item.name" [value]="item.value">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" #submitBtn>
</ form>
```

in ts file

```
@ViewChild('submitBtn') submitBtn: ElementRef;



submitForm() {
    this.submitBtn.nativeElement.click();
}
```

after that call the `submitForm()` function from where you want to submit the function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using  HTMLFormElement.

```
<form ngNoForm name="myForm" id="myForm" [action]="urlvalue" method="POST">
 <button type="submit" class="test" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>
</form>
```

This code in the component.
     const form: HTMLFormElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
      form.submit();